# How do we format in CSS multiple HTML input fields in a row? Different browsers change the placing of the input fields

Tags: html, css, mobile, formatting, input-field

Here is our code.  I am new to CSS so I realize that there maybe an easier way to code the CSS.

The problem is that on mobile devices my input boxes, which should be in rows,  Overlaps and moves to the next line.  Is there a way to format so our input boxes show up consistently (in different browsers and mobile devices) in the correct row?

We removed some of the duplicate css for many of the input fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Legacy Club Scorecard</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
       

        #pname { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align:    left;    display: inline-block;}
    #hone { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #htwo { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #hthree{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height:20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #hfour{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #hfive{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #hsix{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #hseven{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #height{ position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #hnine{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #totalOut{ position: relative; font-weight: bold; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    
    #calcscore{ margin-left: 12px; width: 23%; height: 35px; text-align: center;}
    #calcscore2{ margin-left: 12px; width: 23%; height: 35px; text-align: center;}
    
    #p2name { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: left;}
    #p2hone { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #p2htwo { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2hthree{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height:20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2hfour{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2hfive{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #p2hsix{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2hseven{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2height{ position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2hnine{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p2totalOut{ position: relative; font-weight: bold; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    /*#total{ position: relative; width: 35px; height: 25px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}*/  
    
    #up_down { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #up_down_one { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #up_down_two { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_three { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height:20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_four { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_five { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #up_down_six { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_seven { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_eight { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_nine { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_totalOut{ position: relative; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
       
    #p3name { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: left;}
    #p3hone { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #p3htwo { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3hthree { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height:20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3hfour{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3hfive{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #p3hsix{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3hseven{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3height{ position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3hnine{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p3totalOut{ position: relative; font-weight: bold; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    /*#calcscore{ margin-left: 12px; width: 125px; height: 40px; text-align: center;}*/

    #p4name { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: left;}
    #p4hone { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #p4htwo { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4hthree{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4hfour{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4hfive{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #p4hsix{ position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4hseven{ position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4height{ position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4hnine{ position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #p4totalOut{ position: relative; font-weight: bold; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    /*#total{ position: relative; width: 35px; height: 25px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}*/  
    
    #up_down2 { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #up_down_one2 { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #up_down_two2 { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_three2 { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_four2 { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_five2 { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #up_down_six2 { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_seven2 { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_eight2 { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_nine2 { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #up_down_totalOut2 { position: relative; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    
    #par { position: relative; margin-left: 12px; width: 23.8%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #par_one { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.4%; height: 20px; text-align: center;}
    #par_two { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_three { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.5%; height:20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_four { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_five { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}       
    #par_six { position: relative; width: 5.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_seven { position: relative; margin:-5px; width: 5.7%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_eight { position: relative; width: 5.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_nine { position: relative; margin: -5px; width: 5.3%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    #par_Out{ position: relative; font-weight: bold; width: 7.6%; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;}
    
   
    
    .my_text {
            font-family:    Lucida Handwriting;
            font-size:      15px;
            font-weight:    bold;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    
    .wrapper {
            
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 475px; /* 20px smaller, to fit the paddings on the sides */
                            
           /* padding-right: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;*/ 
            
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border-radius: 0; 
            width: auto!important;
            overflow-x: hidden!important;
           
        }
        

        
        textarea,
        #par, #par_one, #par_two, #par_three, #par_four,
        #par_five, #par_six, #par_seven, #par_eight, #par_nine,
        #par_Out, #par_back, #par_ten, #par_eleven, #par_twelve,
        #par_thirteen, #par_fourteen, #par_fifteen, #par_sixteen,
        #par_seventeen, #par_eighteen, #par_in, #par_total, #not_used1, #not_used2,
        #up_down, #up_down2, #back_up_down, #back_up_down2,
        input.text,
        input[type="text"],
        input[type="submit"],
        .input-checkbox {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
```

Legacy Club Scorecard Front Nine A
       
        
    
        
           
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
     
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
              
        
       
        
        
        
        
        
                
        Legacy Club Scorecard Back Nine

```
    <input type="text" id="p4init" name="p4init" >
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numberic" id="p4hten" name="p4hten">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4heleven" name="p4heleven">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4htwelve" name="p4htwelve">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4hthirteen" name="p4hthirteen">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4hfourteen" name="p4hfourteen">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4hfifteen" name="p4hfifteen">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4hsixteen" name="p4hsixteen">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4hseventeen" name="p4hseventeen">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" id="p4heighteen" name="p4heighteen">
    <input type="text" id="p4totalIn" name="p4totalIn">
    <input type="text" id="p4totalscore" name="p4totalscore">
    <input type="text" id="p4hcp" name="p4hcp">
    <input type="text" id="p4gross" name="p4gross">
    
    <input id="back_up_down2" value="+/-" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_ten2" name="up_down_ten22">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_eleven2" name="up_down_eleven2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_twelve2" name="up_down_twelve2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_thirteen2" name="up_down_thirteen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_fourteen2" name="up_down_fourteen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_fifteen2" name="up_down_fifteen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_sixteen2" name="up_down_sixteen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_seventeen2" name="up_down_seventeen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_eighteen2" name="up_down_eighteen2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_totalIn2" name="up_down_totalIn2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_total2" name="up_down_total2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_hcp2" name="up_down_hcp2">
    <input type="text" id="up_down_gross2" name="up_down_gross2">
    
     <img src="Images/legacyscorecardwback.jpg" alt="Legacy Back Nine Women" width="475" height="75">
    
     <br><br>
    
    <input type="button" id="calcscore2" name="calcscore2" value="Calculate Score" onclick="add_number()">
    
    <br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Miquel!

Welcome aboard!

So, with this giant block of code - it will help us all to break it into a smaller chunk of code:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="dog">What type of dog?</label>
  <input id="dog" type="text">
</div>
```

It's important to have labels for your form elements. This little div wrapper is one way to organize the content.

If you have a long "list" of form elements, then you might want to put it in a *list*.

```
<ul class="thing-list">
  <li class="thing">
    <div class="field">
      <label for="dog">What type of dog?</label>
      <input id="dog" type="text">
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>etc.</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bouaw0hj/

Now, you can control the format of the items by setting flex properties on the parent (in this case .thing-list)

This way, we can be sure that there are no other conflicts with other parts of your project.

So, this might not be a full answer - but hopefully - it can help you continue to ask your question. : )